# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined when insert data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this error when inserting data into a table (mysql) using pdo.

here is my code:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO t_user (UserEmail, UserPassword, UserFirstName, UserLastName, UserSex, UserPhoneNumbers, UserNationalIdCardNo
, UserBirthday, UserAddress, UserDetails, UserRoles, UserDecription) VALUES (:UserEmail, :UserPassword, :UserFirstName, :UserLastName, :UserSex, :UserPhoneNumbers
, :UserNationalIdCardNo, :UserBirthday, :UserAddress, :UserDetails, :UserRoles, :UserDecription)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserEmail', $entity->UserEmail);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserPassword', md5($entity->UserPassword));
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserFirstName', $entity->UserFirstName);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserLastName', $entity->UserLastName);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserSex', $entity->UserSex);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserPhoneNumbers', json_encode($entity->UserPhoneNumbers));
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserNationalIdCardNo', $entity->UserNationalIdCardNo);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserBirthday', $entity->UserBirthday);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserAddress', $entity->UserAddress);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserDetails', $entity->UserDetails);
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserRoles', json_encode($entity->UserRoles));
        $stmt->bindValue(':UserDescription', $entity->UserDescription);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
```

please help me

Comment: `UserDescription` != `UserDecription`.

Comment: @tkausl solved. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled `:UserDecription`, in your query, it should be `:UserDescription`